# How calculate the transformation matrix from one area/rectangle to another in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix

The `Drawing2D.Matrix` in WinForms had this constructor:

```
public Matrix(
    Rectangle rect,
    Point[] plgpts
)
```

...which created a matrix with the correct data to describe the transformation from the given rectangle to the area described by the given points.

How can I generate a Matrix the same way in WPF? The `Windows.Media.Matrix` does not have the same constructor.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific I am asking how to get the same **transformation data** from **two regions/rectangles** in WPF. The old Matrix had this functionality in it's constructor, but I cannot find a way to do this in WPF.

Comment: icemanind - That is not the same question. I am asking how to achieve the same transformation, not how to create a `Drawing2D.Matrix`.

Comment: How about something like the following:
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(1,1,1,1,0,0)

Comment: Sounds more like the question is how to convert a Drawing2D.Matrix to a Media.Matrix, the opposite of the referenced "duplicate".

Comment: @PeterRitchie I think he meant to have something similar to `Drawing2D.Matrix` in WPF but `Matrix` in WPF is a different thing.

Comment: I think the `Matrix` in WPf is not capable of what `Drawing2D.Matrix` does but they do have some similar thing. They both represent some transform. You should look into the `Drawing2D.Matrix.Elements` property and try putting it into a WPF `Matrix` constructor. I believe the `Elements` here is exactly what you need to build a WPF `Matrix` instance. (of course that means you still have to use the `Drawing2D.Matrix` to get the `Elements`).

Comment: @KingKing Yes that is what I mean. I have updated my question title since it wasn't very clear initially.

Comment: @KingKing King yes, and that is why I am asking if there is a WPF way to do it. I am new to the new Matrix and Transforms in WPF and so far have not been able to find the matching functionality.

Comment: @MikeWebb depending on the three points you pass into the c'tor you could be rotating, scaling, or skewing the rectangle.  Maybe `RotateTransform`, `ScaleTransform`, or `SkewTransform` is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the WPF Matrix does not provide a constructor or factory method with such a functionality.

You may however simply create a WPF Matrix from the `Elements` property of the Drawing2D.Matrix like shown below. You'll need to add a reference to the `System.Drawing` assembly in your WPF project.

```
var drawing2dMatrix = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(rect, points);

var wpfMatrix = new System.Windows.Media.Matrix(
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[0],
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[1],
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[2],
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[3],
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[4],
    drawing2dMatrix.Elements[5]);
```

Comment: Yes, so far this seems to be the only way to do it. If you come across a WPF way to do it without requiring the `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` reference, let me know.